# Import file from top of hierarchy folder

Tags: python

I can't import variable "Base" from file (dataBase.py) of top of hierarchy structure like this:
[Structure and file dataBase.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYK24.png)

Content of Store.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from dataBase import Base


class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stores'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

line: "from dataBase import Base" doesn't work - I'm getting:

```
File "Store/Store.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dataBase import Base
ImportError: No module named 'dataBase'
```

I tried to add to all folders a file:

```
__init__.py
```

but the error is still the same like before.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try instead

```
# file dataBase
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class MY_OBJECT(Base):
  # your mappings here

# other file looking for base
import dataBase
base = dataBase.Base # access your base like this
```

works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Put the full path to the directory the file is under into `sys.path.insert`. For example, If the full path to `dataBase` were `C:/Users/Me/RentalApp/dataBase`. You can do:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Users/Me/RentalApp')

from dataBase import Base
```